# Open Source URL with login and password

Tags: c++, networking, ms-media-foundation

I am working on preparing a Media Foundation session that reads a video stream from a network security camera, displays it on screen and encodes it to disk.  I have everything working with a webcam and now I'm trying to connect to the network camera using the `IMFSourceResolver`'s `CreateObjectFromURL()`.  The problem is that the camera requires a login and password and formatting the URL as:

`rtsp://login:password@IPaddr`

still results in a "permission denied" response.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee318413(v=vs.85).aspx) has a few pages on using `IMFNetCredentialManager` to provide the user name and password, but it is not working and I still get permission denied.  Using WireShark I can see that the camera responds with the "Unauthorized" RTSP response to the first MF connection attempt, and then MF just gives up and doesn't check the credential manager, ending in failure.

I don't find any other example using `IMFNetCredentialManager` out there. It seems like reading a video stream from an IP camera that requires a password should be a common task yet I can find no evidence of it being done in practice.  Is it possible to do with Media Foundation or is there another approach that I missed?

Comment: Every IP camera have some small differences. My suggestion is to test first using VLC your connection string. So you understand correctly how to connect to the rtsp stream. In addition if you can take my suggestion, try to use libVLC for this task which I have used for few years and it's open. See this for reference: https://www.brickcom.com/support/faq_contents.php?id=7

Comment: I can connect to the camera with VLC using the same URL.  However VLC pops a dialog asking for username and password.  This is the part I am struggling with using Media Foundation.  I'll check libVLC, thanks!

Comment: @geekus42: that implies that either VLC is ignoring the credentials in the URL and not sending them to the webcam, or it is sending them but the webcam is rejecting them. Either way, the webcam is then prompting VLC for new credentials.

Comment: @geekus42: Have you tried to follow this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473824(v=vs.85).aspx? It should work.

Comment: @VuVirt:  I have now carefully followed all of the steps on these MSDN pages.  I have the IMFNetCredentialManager and I have passed it as a property when calling the SourceResolver's CreateObjectFromURL().  However it looks like BeginGetCredentials() is never called by Media Foundation when trying to open the URL.  I must be missing something.  Since VLC knows it needs credentials with the same URL I don't know why MF would not.

Comment: From MSDN:  "The network sources uses the credential manager to get user credentials. If the network source requires credentials to access a network resource, it calls the application's IMFNetCredentialManager::BeginGetCredentials method."  So I guess MF doesn't think it requires credentials?

Answer (score 0):

After completing my research, here is the conclusion that I have reached.

Windows Media Foundation provides good (but not thorough) support for USB webcams and basic streaming.  It is just a foundation though.  Anything more advanced like communicating with a networked IP camera requires a lot of extra work by the programmer to fully implement their protocol of choice, like RTSP, HTTP or ONVIF.

I was expecting that I could set up a media session for a webcam and then simply switch the source to a network camera with RTSP by using the source resolver with a URL.  Authorization using the network credential manager as shown in MSDN is not part of the media source provided by Media Foundation, which is why BeginGetCredentials() is not called.  It is just an example of what you need to implement with your own scheme.

My solution is therefore to abandon using Media Foundation and go with a 3rd party library from LEADTOOLS, etc.  It costs money, but otherwise it would cost a lot more development time for me to create what I need.

I hope this answer helps save someone all the time I spent chasing this rabbit into the abyss!

Comment: Since you mentioned LEADTOOLS, we recommend making full use of the free evaluation period before you decide to purchase. If you need any assistance, we offer free email and online chat support both during evaluation and after purchasing.